# How to configure proxy to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, etl, datastage

I am new in AWS services. In my development environment I create an ETL that calls the client of amazon an upload files to Amazon S3. It works well.

However, when I tried to use this code in production environment, I had an error related to Proxy. I attach the image of the error:

[image: Proxy Error AWS]

I hope someone can help me with this error.

Comment: Don't use all-uppercase title. And [no taglines please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Can you provide more information about your configuration -- are you using a Proxy to access AWS? What is the different between your Development environment that works and the Production environment that doesn't work? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.